# How to disable WLAN Isolation on router ZTE F609?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, network-shares, home-networking

How to disable WLAN / Wireless Isolation on ZTE F609?

Because i can't find it. I can't ping my Wireless to Wired

Comment: I have the same issue on ZTE F668. Devices from wired network cannot ping on wireless devices and viceversa. Tjere is an isolation between wired and wireless. That setting from the answer does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I disable WLAN / Wireless Isolation on ZTE F609?

Network > Network > Basic > Uncheck "Enable Isolation"

[image]

Source [ZTE F609 WLAN Basic Router Screenshot - PortForward.com](http://screenshots.portforward.com/routers/ZTE/F609/WLAN_Basic.htm)

Answer (score 0):

On my F670, I had to take attention to these two points :

- "Network / WLAN Radio2.4G / Basic / Enable Isolation" unticked (also for "WLAN Radio5G") ;
- "Network / LAN / DHCP Port Service / Dhcp Mode": Lan for the SSID you use.

I do not use the default LAN configuration (not 192.168.1.0/24), and without the DHCP mode to LAN, I did not have access to Internet from my wireless devices. With DHCP mode to LAN, I get access to Internet AND I am able to ping between wired and wireless devices.

Answer (score 0):

On F670 and newer F609 with gigabit ports there is another isolation toggle switch in Network/LAN.

However I have come accross a carrier firmware F609 that has the page but will not retain the setting after reboot, could be a bug or carrier policy restriction.

[F670 Lan to Lan Isolation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMx7N.png)